# Answer Set Programming #Count cardinality constraint

Tags: solver, answer-set-programming, clingo

I'm a complete beginner at ASP.

```
adj(c11,c12). adj(c12,c13). adj(c13,c14).
adj(c21,c22). adj(c22,c23). adj(c23,c24).
adj(c31,c32). adj(c32,c33). adj(c33,c34).

adj(c11,c21). adj(c12,c22). adj(c13,c23). adj(c14,c24).
adj(c21,c31). adj(c22,c32). adj(c23,c33). adj(c24,c34).

adj(c11,c22). adj(c12,c21). adj(c12,c23). adj(c13,c22). adj(c13,c24). adj(c14,c23).
adj(c21,c32). adj(c22,c31). adj(c22,c33). adj(c23,c32). adj(c23,c34). adj(c24,c33).

{mine(F)} <= 1 :- adj(F,C).
:- #count {mine(F) : adj(F,X)} <= 2.
```

So I am generating a minesweeper game. At the moment I have the mines generated into different cells. However my #Count is not working, how do I limit each mine to be `<=` 2 in each answer set?

Answer (score 0):

## Answer to question

The current definition of mines is:

```
{mine(F)} <= 1 :- adj(F,C).   % generation
:- #count {mine(F) : adj(F,X)} <= 2.   % restriction
```

The *generation* is saying: *for all tiles found in first argument of atom F, there is one or zero mine*.
The *restriction* is saying: *for all tiles found in first argument of atom F, there is one or zero mine*, which is always true because if there is either a mine or not a mine.

The count constraint should be write as:

```
:- #count{F: mine(F)} > 2.
```

Or, more simply:

```
:- {mine(_)} > 2.
```

## Alternative (simpler) way

In order to get between `m` and `n` mines in the field, we should then yield between `m` and `n` atoms `mine(F)` where `F` is one tile name. (like `c12`).
This can be done with *generation* without *restriction*:

```
% tile(T) holds for all identifier used in adj/2 atoms.
tile(T):- adj(T,_).
tile(T):- adj(_,T).

% yield between m and n mines (with m=0 and n=2)
0 {mine(F): tile(F)} 2.
```

This will output the 79 models that contains 0, 1 or 2 mines.